# What is the common good practice on Github Software Development in reality?

Tags: github, project-management

Being a software development student, I've recently studied some concepts and tools like GitHub and Docker. And I'm interested in the industry or community “Good Practice” for using GitHub in software collaboration. As I understand, these practices are rules followed by experts in general to enhance the development process.

So far, my coursework has introduced me to several practices, such as creating branches for changes instead of directly altering the main branch; submitting changes via pull requests for peer approval, forcing reviews by one or more team members; clearly labeled and titled issues for easy identification; committing small changes (but not making large change in one commit); writing meaningful commit messages; using Docker for managing dependencies; specifying exact versions of dependencies; implementing GitHub Actions for CI/CD; maintaining a detailed README.

[Question] Considering these rules might be fit or not based on project scale and nature, so let say now you are in a team with small to medium-sized projects, specifically a web application with data analysis features, in a team of 4-10, what practice other than above would you appreciate if your teammate do it? (I am not sure the practice I listed above is suitable for real world, but I guess in certain degree it is good for software development)

Additionally, I'm open to exploring alternative methods and tools beyond GitHub for software development collaboration.

Comment: *best practices* questions are opinion-based, and therefore are off-topic here. This site is for specific questions about problems that you're having with programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). There's nothing specific about what you're asking. For more information, see [What questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And, for future reference, questions asking us to recommend or find tools  (as you did in your last paragraph) are off-topic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You should ask this kind of questions on [Discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions) section of StackOverflow.

---

You pretty much outline and know the basic good practices.

As for general workflow there is no one fits all golden rule.
You should research it yourself and try out different tools in your team.
Often times it is just matter of preference.
*For example I hate MS Projects but there are plenty of people who like it.*

Some Suggestions:

For small team project management you can use GitHub Projects, or Trello.

For communication: slack

GitHub Discussions is also a good tool to be used during development.

Alternative to GitHub is Gitlab and many people praise Gitlab for its CI/CD implementation.

Using Docker alone is good enough for smaller or simpler projects but once your project gets more complicated, you may inevitably need to start using [Kubernetes.](https://kubernetes.io/)

---

#### Git

In the case of using git, it is called `workflow`

There are many workflow

1. Feature branching/GitHub Flow
2. Trunk Based Flow
3. Git Feature Flow
4. Git Flow
5. Enhanced Git Flow
6. One Flow
7. GitLab Flow
8. Forking Workflow

Check them out yourself and choose the one you seem the most appropriate for your use case.

### Links:

##### Centralized Workflow

1. https://www.atlassian.com/ja/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows
2. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#centralized-workflow

##### Trunk Based Flow

1. https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/trunk-based-development/
2. https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/feature-flags/
3. https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/feature-toggle/
4. https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html
5. https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/
6. https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/continuous-integration/trunk-based-development

##### Feature branching/GitHub Flow

1. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow
2. https://www.atlassian.com/ja/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow
3. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow
4. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
5. https://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

##### Git Flow

1. https://www.atlassian.com/ja/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
2. https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
3. https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/git-flow

##### Enhanced Git Flow

1. https://www.toptal.com/gitflow/enhanced-git-flow-explained

##### Git Feature Flow

1. https://medium.com/dev-managers-handbook/git-feature-flow-125d28dfef1e

##### GitLab Flow

1. https://github.com/jadsonjs/gitlab-flow
2. https://microfluidics.utoronto.ca/gitlab/help/topics/gitlab_flow.md
3. https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-gitlab-flow/
4. https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-are-gitlab-flow-best-practices/

##### One Flow

1. https://www.endoflineblog.com/oneflow-a-git-branching-model-and-workflow

##### Forking Workflow

1. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow

##### General

1. https://nira.com/git-flow-vs-github-flow/
2. https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/best-practices/git-branch-strategy
3. https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf

Comment: You put an awful lot of work into answering a question that is off-topic here and should not have been asked. We try not to answer off-topic questions here, because people use that to justify asking other off-topic questions in the future - someone later will find this question and use it to justify asking another one like it, even after this one has been closed.